# Spring Data JDBC one-to-many relation causes lots of log warnings

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc, bidirectional-relation

Summary: Spring Data emits warnings as it `SELECT`s the the same column twice. The warning is:

```
(...) WARN o.s.d.j.core.convert.ResultSetAccessor   : ResultSet contains id multiple times
```

This is `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` via Spring Boot 2.5.5 ([documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.2.5/reference/html/#jdbc.repositories)). I'm working with a very basic one-to-many relationship:

[image]

I've reduced the entity classes as much as possible for brevity, while retaining the warnings:

**Outlet.java**

```
(...)
@Table("outlet")
public class Outlet {
    @Id
    private String outletId;
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "outlet_id", keyColumn = "id")
    private Map<String, OfferedService> offeredServices;
    (...)
}
```

**OfferedService.java**

```
(...)
@Table("offered_service")
public class OfferedService {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String outletId;
    (...)    
}
```

The repository is also most basic...

**OutletRepository.java**

```
(...)
public interface OutletRepository extends CrudRepository<Outlet, String> {}
```

...and in my application code, I just do a `findAll` on this repository:

```
(...)
outletRepo.findAll();
(...)
```

This leads to a query which selects the the same column twice, and subsequently a warning from Spring Data's `ResultSetAccessor`:

```
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [
    SELECT "outlet"."outlet_id" AS "outlet_id" FROM "outlet"]
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [
    SELECT "offered_service"."id" AS "id", 
        "offered_service"."outlet_id" AS "outlet_id", 
        "offered_service"."id" AS "id"
    FROM "offered_service"
    WHERE "offered_service"."outlet_id" = ?]
TRACE o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: 
    column index 1, parameter value [xyz012], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
WARN  o.s.d.j.core.convert.ResultSetAccessor   : ResultSet contains id multiple times
WARN  o.s.d.j.core.convert.ResultSetAccessor   : ResultSet contains id multiple times
(...repeated many times...)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, for `findAll`, shouldn't this be a `JOIN` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things that get mapped to the column `offered_service.outlet_id`:
The one-to-many mapping from `Outlet` to `OfferedService` and the attribute `OfferedService.outletId`.

If these are supposed to be different you can use annotations to change the columns these are mapped to, but I assume you are intentionally doing this, to have the `outletId` available in the `OfferedService` entity.

While this works, it is kind of a hack and might break in future versions.

The recommended way of doing something like this is to make `outletId` transient using `@Transient` and use plain java code to set its value when an `OfferedService` is added to an `Outlet`.

There is an blog article about just that: https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/22/spring-data-jdbc-how-do-i-make-bidirectional-relationships

There also seems to be another problem where Spring Data JDBC does select the `OfferedService.id` twice. I'm not sure why that happens. Looks like a bug to me. But you probably can remove the `id` completely since the map key and the `outlet_id` should form a perfectly fine primary key.

Comment: Thanks for answering and the links! On the assumption: I don't actually need the backref `OfferedService.outletId` in the java object and found out that I can remove it, so I did just that. However, doing so does not stop the warnings `ResultSet contains id multiple times` from showing up. Can I do anything against those besides altering log levels?

Comment: Removing the `id` field gets rid of the warning - thank you! The lesson for me here is that not all columns of a table need to be a part of the corresponding `@Table`-annotated object. In this case the ID of `OfferedService` will "live" just in the keys of the `Map` in `Outlet`, which should be OK for my use case. One question remains: Should `spring-data-jdbc` work with a setup like given in the question and without the warnings? I can offer to open an issue at github with a minimal example including test data.

Comment: Opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/1073)...